# filtering list of dicts by multiply parameters

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries and at this point my code checks if `product_id` is the same and then it adds to result only 1 line and sums up `qty`.

Problem is that it should sum up quantity for lines that are with the same cost, and if the cost is different it should add it as another line. Trying to do this for 6 hours with no luck, so I'm asking for help here.

```py
values = [
    {
        'status': u'Purchase',
        'phantom': False,
        'row_no': 1,
        'product_id': product.product(29793,),
        'standard_price': 29.8533333333333,
        'qty': 8.0,
        'cost': 4.78
    },
    {
        'status': u'Purchase',
        'phantom': False,
        'row_no': 2,
        'product_id': product.product(29793,),
        'standard_price': 29.8533333333333,
        'qty': 2.0,
        'cost': 80.0
    },
    {
        'status': u'Purchase',
        'phantom': False,
        'row_no': 3,
        'product_id': product.product(29793,),
        'standard_price': 29.8533333333333,
        'qty': 2.0,
        'cost': 80.0
    }
]

seen = set()
result = []
sum_res = {}

for dic in values:
    key = (dic['product_id'])
    if key in seen:
        for k, v in sum_res.iteritems():
            if k == key:
                sum_res[k] += dic['qty']
        continue
    sum_res[dic['product_id']] = dic['qty']
    result.append(dic)

    seen.add(key)

row = 0

for dict in result:
    row += 1
    for k, v in sum_res.iteritems():
        if k == dict['product_id']:
            dict['qty'] = v
            dict['row_no'] = row

# summed_results = []

for dic in result:
    dic['sum_cost'] = dic['qty'] * dic['cost']
```

**My OUTPUT:**

```py
result = [
    {
        'status': u'Purchase',
        'phantom': False, 
        'sum_cost': 57.36,
        'row_no': 1,
        'product_id': product.product(29793,),
        'standard_price': 29.8533333333333,
        'qty': 12.0,
        'cost': 4.78
    }
]
```

**Desired OUTPUT:**

```py
result = [
    {
        'status': u'Purchase',
        'phantom': False,
        'sum_cost': 38.24,
        'row_no': 1,
        'product_id': product.product(29793,),
        'standard_price': 29.8533333333333,
        'qty': 8.0,
        'cost': 4.78
    },
    {
        'status': u'Purchase',
        'phantom': False,
        'sum_cost': 320,
        'row_no': 2,
        'product_id': product.product(29793,), 
        'standard_price': 29.8533333333333,
        'qty': 4.0,
        'cost': 80
    }
]
```

Comment: is it intended that the product id is 3 times the same?

Comment: where did you get the product.product is another method?

Comment: @Sadap yep it's totally realistic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = [
    {'status': u'Purchase', 'phantom': False, 'row_no': 1, 'product_id': 29793, 'standard_price': 29.8533333333333,
     'qty': 8.0, 'cost': 4.78},
    {'status': u'Purchase', 'phantom': False, 'row_no': 2, 'product_id':
        29793, 'standard_price': 29.8533333333333, 'qty': 2.0, 'cost': 80.0},
    {'status': u'Purchase', 'phantom': False, 'row_no': 3, 'product_id':
        29793, 'standard_price': 29.8533333333333, 'qty': 2.0, 'cost': 80.0}]

seen = set()
result = []
sum_res = defaultdict(int)
row = 0

for dic in values:
    key = (dic['product_id'], dic['cost'])
    sum_res[key] += dic['qty']

    if key not in seen:
        result.append(dic)
        seen.add(key)

for dic in result:
    key = (dic['product_id'], dic['cost'])
    row += 1
    dic['row_no'] = row
    dic['qty'] = sum_res[key]
    dic['sum_cost'] = dic['qty'] * dic['cost']

print(result)
```